# Change UIAlertController tintColor globally Xcode 11/iOS13

Tags: ios, swift

Changing the `tintColor` of the `UIAlertController`s used to be possible to change via the `window`'s `tintColor`. This was usually done in the `AppDelegate` and it would affect `UIAlertController`s tintColor as well. Unfortunately in projects started with Xcode 11 for iOS SDK 13 there is no window in the `AppDelegate` anymore.

Where do I need to set the `tintColor`, so that all `UIAlertController`s use it?

Things I tried:

- setting the `tintColor` of the first `UIViewController`'s `.view.window`. Unfortunately the `window` is `nil`.
- setting the main Storyboard's `globalTint` color. This affects the navigation bars and is also inherited by other UI elements, but not by the UIAlertController.
- It would be an option to write an extension to the UIAlertController. But this not the clean way. There must be a better way.
- I checked several answers to similar questions but for older Xcode versions. The answers do not apply.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get access to the window using `windowScene` for iOS 13+:

```
let windowScene = UIApplication.shared
                .connectedScenes
                .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
                .first
if let windowScene = windowScene as? UIWindowScene {
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene) // now you've access to the window
}
```

Comment: calling this on the first view controller's `viewDidAppear` yields a `window`. Unfortunately right after setting a color, the color of the `window` is `nil` again and there is no effect on the `UIAlertController`. Acutally the returned `window` is a different instance on each call.